# Why do we get a CInt "Invalid Use of Null" Error?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

We are experiencing a 500 server error when no option is selected for the payment dropdown field. The db accepts null. The server log file outputs this error:

> 800a005e|Invalid_use_of_Null:_'CInt' HTTP/1.1

The error log refers to this line:

```
If cint(iPaymentIdRS) = cint(iPaymentId) then selPayment = selPayment & " selected "
```

---

Note: our ASP developer is currently not available, so a simplified answer is appreciated.

- We added the value "no payment option selected" to the empty dropdown field.
- We made sure that the DB accepts null.
- We searched online for a solution but did not find one.

```vb
If sOperation = "Edit" then


    iPaymentId      = Request.Form("cboPayment") :If iPaymentId = "0" then iPaymentId = null



'**********Payment**********************

selPayment = "<option value=""0"">"

Do While rs.EOF = false
    iPaymentIdRS = rs("PaymentId")

    selPayment = selPayment & "<option value=""" & iPaymentIdRS & """"
    If cint(iPaymentIdRS) = cint(iPaymentId) then selPayment = selPayment & " selected "    
    selPayment = selPayment & ">" & rs("PaymentDesc")

    rs.MoveNext
loop
```

I expect that an empty (null) value does not return a 500 error, but is accepted. The payment dropdown field is not mandatory.

Comment: ASP.Net with VBScript?? There is no such combination, you could be running ASP.Net using VB.Net or Classic ASP with VBScript, which is it?

Comment: Judging by the code snippet it’s Classic ASP as ASP.Net would likely use a `SqlDataReader` to iterate over records.

Answer (score 3):

The error is being caused by applying `CInt` to a nulled variable.

`iPaymentId` is being set to null if `Request.Form("cboPayment")` is 0, and `CInt(iPaymentId)` is then trying to convert `iPaymentId` to an integer regardless of its value. Converting a nulled variable to an integer isn't allowed in VBscript.

The line...

```vb
If CInt(iPaymentIdRS) = CInt(iPaymentId) Then selPayment = selPayment & " selected "
```

...doesn't need to run if `iPaymentId` is null. To verify that `iPaymentId` has been assigned a numerical value before running the comparison, change it to:

```vb
If IsNumeric(iPaymentId) Then : If CInt(iPaymentIdRS) = CInt(iPaymentId) Then selPayment = selPayment & " selected "
```

If `iPaymentId` is null the comparison won't run and the error won't occur.

Answer (score 0):

iPaymentId      = Request.Form("cboPayment")
iPaymentId = iPaymentID + 0

should convert it to integer so null, text, etc. values will pass